# Proof of Vandermonde Matrix Inverse Formula

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, inverse

I'm working through Exercise 40 from section 1.2.3 of Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* volume 1, but am finding myself unable to produce a rigorous proof, and the one [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix) is suspect and not quite clear enough (for me, at least) in some of the steps; in particular, how to "[identify] the $k$th order coefficient in [the] two polynomials."

The problem is this: given a Vandermonde matrix $[x_j^i]_n$, show that the inverse is given by

$$
[b_{ij}]_n = \left[
\frac{
   \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k_1 < \dotsc < k_{n-j} \leq n\\k_1,\dotsc,k_{n-j} \neq i}} (-1)^{j-1} x_{k_1} \dotsc x_{k_{n-j}}
}{
   x_i \prod_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n\\k \neq i}} (x_k - x_i)
}
\right]_n\text{.}
$$

The author gives a hint by stating that the sum in the above numerator is just the coefficient of $x^{j-1}$ in the polynomial $(x_1-x)\dotsc(x_n-x)/(x_i-x)$; and he gives an intermediate result showing the explicit multiplication of the matrix and its inverse as

$$
   \sum_{1 \leq t \leq n}b_{it}x_j^t
   =
   \frac{
      x_j \prod_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n\\k \neq i}} (x_k - x_j)
   }{
      x_i \prod_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n\\k \neq i}} (x_k - x_i)
   }
   =
   \delta_{ij}\text{.}
$$

The only other hint as to the type of solution he was expecting is a reference to A. de Moivre's *The Doctrine of Chances*, 2nd edition, pp. 197-199, which deals with polynomial recurrence relations and difference products (available [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=PII_AAAAcAAJ&dq=moivre%20doctrine%20of%20chances%202nd%20ed&pg=PA197#v=onepage&q=moivre%20doctrine%20of%20chances%202nd%20ed&f=false)).

At the least, I was just hoping someone could either verify the proof is correct at `proofwiki` and possibly fill in exactly how one identifies the $k$th order coefficient in the proof; or perhaps explain a proof strategy as to what steps to take where the intermediate result is obtained at some point before the final result.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: I believe the proof is correct, the coefficient of $x^k$ in the lagrange Interpolation formula is simply Vieta's formula ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas )

Comment: Proof looks good. It is not a hint, but a fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just done some editing on the proof of Vandermonde's matrix inverse on proofwiki:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix

I hope that was what you were asking for :)

Comment: It would be better to post the relevant work here, in case someone edits your changes on that wiki in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Marin, the proof certainly does seem to be more rigorous now from how I remember it was previously. It's also nice to see concrete references to concepts such as _Lagrange basis polynomials_ with which I'm not so familiar with, and had omitted from my own [attempt](http://tord.name/section.1.2.3.html), which admittedly involved a bit of 'hand waving' at the time. ;) Thanks for your edits.

Comment: the link to proofwiki is not working.