# Inverse of matrix with particular structure

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a square invertible matrix $A=[c, c^2, c^3 \dots c^n]$ where $c \in \Bbb R^n$. Are there any known fast tricks for inverting it?

**Edit**: $c$ is a column vector and raising it to a power is to raise every value in the column to that power. The matrix is a concatenation of these column vectors.

Comment: What does $c^k$ mean?

Comment: What's $c^3$? Is it $(c_1^3, c_2^3, c_3^3, \dots, c_n^3)$?

Comment: It isn't clear what structure you are ascribing to $A$.  Are the "entries" $c,c^2,c^3,\ldots$ meant to be diagonal blocks?  What does $c^n$ mean for $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If @Roland has suggested the right interpretation, this $A$ is related (closely) to the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), which comes up in connection with polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @hardmath you can not imagine how helpful that link has been! Thank you!!

Comment: This post might be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698254/proof-of-vandermonde-matrix-inverse-formula

Comment: @MartinSleziak: It is indeed. The link provided there (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde's_Matrix) shows how to derive a formula for $(A^T)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix (I am changing the nomenclature for convenience) being considered is:

$$ C = \begin{pmatrix}  
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & \ldots & c_n \\
c_1^2 & c_2^2 & c_3^2 & \ldots & c_n^2 \\
c_1^3 & c_2^3 & c_3^3 & \ldots & c_n^3 \\
    & \ldots & & \ddots &      \\
c_1^n & c_2^n & c_3^n & \ldots & c_n^n \end{pmatrix} $$

Such a matrix is invertible if and only if (a) all the $c_i$ are nonzero and (b) all the $c_i$ are distinct.  A closely related matrix is the *transpose* of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix):

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & \ldots & c_n \\
c_1^2 & c_2^2 & c_3^2 & \ldots & c_n^2 \\
    & \ldots & & \ddots &      \\
c_1^{n-1} & c_2^{n-1} & c_3^{n-1} & \ldots & c_n^{n-1} \end{pmatrix} $$

where $C = AD$ holds for $D = \operatorname{diag}(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$.

Because the Vandermonde matrix is associated with degree $n-1$ polynomial interpolation at a set of distinct arguments $x = c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$, much thought has been given to efficiently solving systems of equations to determine the corresponding coefficients.  One approach to inverting $C$ would thus be to find an inverse of $A^T$ by solving the corresponding $n$ linear systems.

[Golub and van Loan's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801854148), **Matrix Computations**, Sec. 4.6, notes the use of [Newton divided-differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) to solve the interpolation problems $A^T x = b$ in $5n^2/2$ flops (Algorithm 4.6.1).

They also give an equally efficient approach to solving systems $Ax = b$ (Algorithm 4.6.2) which amounts to recasting the divided-difference computations as triangular matrix factorizations of $A^{-1}$.  They cite Bjorck and Pereya (1970), "Solution of Vandermonde Systems of Equations," *Math. Comp. 24*, 893-903, for a description and analysis of both algorithms.