# How to calculate inverse of the special matrix $A_{(m+1)\times (m+1)}$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.
I want to calculate inverse of the matrix $ A_{(m+1)\times (m+1)}$.
$
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1& n&n^2&\cdot&n^m\\
1& n+1&(n+1)^2&\cdot &(n+1)^m\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
1&n+m&(n+m)^2&\cdot&(n+m)^m\\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$

I worked on the problem and found  that:

If $m=1$, then we have
$$
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1& n\\
1& n+1\\
 \end{bmatrix},
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
n+1& -n\\
-1& 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}
$$

If $m=2$, then

$
A^{-1}=(\frac{1}{2!})
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
(n+1)(n+2)& -n(n+2)&-n(n+1)\\
-(2n+3)&2(2n+2)&-(2n+1)\\
1&-2&1
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$

for $m=3$, we set
$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{3!}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)& -n(n+2)(n+3)&-n(n+1)(n+3)&-n(n+1)(n+2)\\
3(n+\frac{6}{3})^2-1&3(n+\frac{5}{3})^2-\frac{7}{3}&3(n+\frac{4}{3})^2-\frac{7}{3}&3(n+\frac{3}{3})^2-1\\
3(n+\frac{6}{3})&-3(n+\frac{5}{3})&3(n+\frac{4}{3})&-3(n+\frac{3}{3})\\
-1&3&-3&1\\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$

I guess explicate form for the first and last rows of the matrix $A^{-1}$are as follows\
$
a_{1j}=\frac{1}{2!}\times(-1)^{j-1}\times\prod_{k=0,k\neq i}^m (n+k)\times\dbinom {m}{j-1};1 \leq j \leq m+1
$
and

$
a_{(m+1)j}=\frac{1}{m!}\times(-1)^{j-1}\times\dbinom {m}{j-1}; 1\leq j \leq m+1 
$

Now, can some body give an explicit formula for  all $a_{ij}?$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems $A_{m}$ is the top $m\times m$ submatrix of $A_{m+1}$, so perhaps you could obtain an inductive formula using the formula for the inverse of a block matrix.

Comment: Have a look at this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of Vandermonde Matrix Inverse Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698254/proof-of-vandermonde-matrix-inverse-formula)